# How to get the generated query string of wp_remote_get?

Tags: wp-remote-get

I have some very basic data that I am posting to a proprietary lead capturing system. Whenever I submit my form data to their system the body of the request is an error 500 page.

I am trying to debug the problem with their developer, it clearly doesn't like something in my query string, and he would like to be able to test it on his end.

However, I've scoured through Google results and the WordPress codex and I cannot find a way to pull the query string that is generated from something like:

> $result = wp_remote_get( 'thirdparty.com', array( 'body' => array(
>   'foo' => 'bar' ) ) );

I would expect the query string to look something like:

```
thirdparty.com?foo=bar
```

Anyone have any tip on how to get this generated URL/query string?

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are pretty good in providing an answer to your question (how to get the generated url), i will answer what i guess you really want to know (how do i get it to call thirdparty.com?foo=bar with wp_remote_get)

The Answer is: the $args array you use to transmit the url parameters won't work like this. If you have to transmit a POST request with wp_remote_post, you would use the body argument like your example. However, to wp_remote_get thirdparty.com?foo=bar, you simply do

```
wp_remote_get('http://thirdparty.com?foo=bar');
```

if you want to get fancy and use an array, you can also do this:

```
$url = "http://thirdparty.com";
$data = array('foo' => 'bar');
$query_url = $url.'?'.http_build_query($data);
$response = wp_remote_get($query_url);
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The Wordpress documentation of wp_remote_get() suggests that you can feed it an array of arguments, but like you said it doesn't work for adding arguments to the URL. Instead, those arguments are options passed to the http request function, like what http version to use etc. However, I think there is a way to use that space for actual URL arguments too, with a nested array:

`$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.php',
    array(
        'args'     => array('apikey' => 'mykey'),
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
    )
);`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into the classes inside [`wp-includes/class-http`](https://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/4.7.3/wp-includes/class-http.php) that handle the actual request. There are various hooks like `http_api_curl` you could hook into to see what is actually requested.

Comment: I'd have to take another look but I had var_dumped each variable after the hook call and they just returned my data as an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a task for **Xdebug**. I'd recommend to use it together with PHPStorm.

Then you'll need to set a breakpoint exactly at the moment you build the query or when you post the request. Then you can inspect what exactly is going on.

Following is a sample chain I used to post something successfully, which results in a query that simply looks like the following which then get appended to the `$url` below. I found it important to format the query with `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` using PHP's [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) so it gets encoded properly.

The query:

```
foo=foovalue&bar=barvalue
```

The complete sample:

```
// Build the URL query to be append to the POST request URL.
$data = [
  'foo' => $foo,
  'bar' => $bar,
];

$query = http_build_query($data, NULL, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

// The POST request URL.
$url = 'https://example.com/index.php/fooBar/save2?' . $query;

$args = [
  'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
  'method'  => 'POST',
];

// Post the request.
$response = wp_remote_request($url, $args);

//Check for success
if (!is_wp_error($response) && ($response['response']['code'] === 200 || $response['response']['code'] === 201)) {
  return $response['body'];
}
```